# Extension to use ticket for discount at checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, extensions, payment, discount

I would like to know if there is an extension that can support the following:

Someone can use redeem tickets for 10% discount on the total value of the products in cart.

The customer should enter at checkout the amount that will be cashed with tickets (until 10%) of the total value.

Is there a extension for that?

Comment: What's the difference to the coupon codes of Magento?

Comment: @fschmengler if a order cost 100 euros , the customer can pay up to 10 euros (10% of total amount) with ticket clippings. This is a service called moneyback in Greece which use the ticket clippings (from bus, theater etc) for pay a part of total amount.